# Stuck and couldn't start The Merryweather Heist

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I switched to Michael, then Franklin, and then Trevor and there are no missions for anyone apart from a blue "B". I went there as Michael and I couldn't activate the mission. Can someone please tell me what I'm meant to do?

Comment: "apart from a blue B" Where is this Blue B? This is useful to pinpoint the mission and check if it has any prerequisites.